# How can I get location detection working on my Pocket TV?

Tags: geolocation

I have an Infinitec Pocket TV (PTV1000 running Android 4.0.4, build ICS02A) and none of the location detection settings seem to work.

Whenever I click the my location icon in Google Maps, I get this message:

> Please enable a My Location source in system settings

The News and Weather app/widget just says "No weather location available" and has an option to enter my location.

In **Settings** -> **Location services** I have both "***Google's location service***: location determined by wifi" and "***Location & Google search***: Let Google use your location to improve search results and other services" ticked, which are the only options in there.

I know that this device doesn't have GPS, but the network location features using wifi and IP should still work the same way they do on my non-GPS & non-3G tablet?